# Longident.flat error when trying to migrate a file from bucklescript to rescript

Tags: bucklescript, rescript

Trying to rescript bucklescript-tea and after using rescript convert -all
All the files converted except for 2 files that handle http stuff this error showed up

Fatal error: Longident.flat
Fatal error: exception Whole_compiler.Misc.Fatal_error

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to narrow it down a bit more. I would suggest taking one of the offending files and either start removing things until it works, or move one definition at a time to a new file until until you get an error. Then you would know exactly which definition is causing the problem. If it's still quite big, you can try narrowing that down even more.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked by removing some definitions

Comment: You might need those definitions though, so figuring out why that specific definition fails still seems worthwhile. But you'd have to show it to us, otherwise we can't be of much help.

Comment: The problem was in Map.String function and it was fixed by changing the format of it.